# adding the drawer of Android Lollipop in Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-layout

I am new to developing applications for Android and I'm starting my first app using the Cordova to emulate html. I wanted to put a native drawer in my application so that when the user clicks on an item in the menu, he performed a certain action in JavaScript and HTML, but do not know how to add. Could someone help me?

I already have an idea (minimum) of how the codes for Adroid and know what to write for it will send an action for Cordova webView.

Drawer that I want:

[image: Android Drawer]

Comment: You might want to use a framework for that. This is [one that I am currently using](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel). It is not native, but it is quite indistinguishable from the real one.

Comment: But if I want to use a native drawer of Android for it? Because frameworks within the Cordova causes bugs and not of a sense of fluidity.